# jQuery datepicker issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I cannot get working my DatePicker for disabling both: weekends and past days (although it works if I leave just one constraint).
How do I bind these two together? (I have been looking and could not find any post on the Internet)

```
$(function () {

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ beforeShowDay: $.datepicker.noWeekends });
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0, maxDate: "+1M +10D" });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using it as below,

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay    : $.datepicker.noWeekends, 
    minDate          : 0, 
    maxDate          : "+1M +10D"  });
```